# Use ViewChild for dynamic elements - Angular 2 & ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, viewchild

I want to use multiple [IonicSlides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) that I added dynamically. But I can't use `@viewChild`. please suggest a way to resolve this problem.

**Template.html :**

```
<div *ngFor="let name of title;let i = index;">
    <ion-slides  id="something" #slides>
        //some code
    </ion-slides>
</div
```

**Component.ts :**

```
  @ViewChild('slides') slides: QueryList<Slides>;

  ....

  ngAfterViewInit(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
              alert(this.slides.toArray()); //this line rise error 
        }, 3000);
  }
```

**Error :**

> _this.slides.toArray is not a function

Comment: Please don't use alerts for debugging, it's 2020

Comment: @refaelio question is for 2 years ago, no 2020. lol

Comment: @Mohsen 2018 is just as bad as 2020, just doesn't sound as cool lol

Comment: @Mohsen it's just a figure of speech

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` , **[Read More](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e)**

> **[@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#viewchild)** :
>
> You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive
>   matching the selector from the view DOM.
>
> **[@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren)** :
>
> You can use ViewChildren to get the QueryList of elements or
>   directives from the view DOM.

Answer (score 2):

`@ViewChild` is for for single element or directive. To get get the `QueryList` of elements or directives from the view DOM, use `@ViewChildren`

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of title;let i = index;" #slides>
    <ion-slides  id="something">
        //some code
    </ion-slides>
</div
```

**Component.ts**

```js
@ViewChildren("slides") private slides: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  ....

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.slides.changes.subscribe(() => console.log(this.slides));
}
```